# How do i print all the information correctly in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, nodes

I want to print out all the information from all the so called "Nodes", i don't know what i want to specify when i want to loop through all my "Nodes". it is important that it works with how many nodes as i want,

I have tried almost all things i can think of such as naming them only numbers and trying to use that to "locate" them in the array.

```
List_of_Nodes = {}
List_of_Names = []


class Nodes:
    def __init__(self, nodeID, parentID):
        self.nodeID = str(nodeID)
        self.parentID = parentID

    def __str__(self):
        return '\nnodeID: {} \nParentID: {} '.format(self.nodeID,self.parentID)

Num_Nodes = int(input("The number of nodes: "))
for n in range(Num_Nodes):
    if n == 0:
        new_nodeID = input("\nPlease enter a name: ")
    else:
        new_nodeID = input("Please enter another name: ")
    List_of_Names.append(new_nodeID)
    Num_Parents = int(input("the number of parents for this node"))
    for n2 in range(Num_Parents):
        if n2 == 0:
            new_parentID = input("Please enter a parentName: ")
        else:
            new_parentID = input("Please enter another parentName:")
        List_of_Nodes[new_nodeID, new_parentID] = Nodes(new_nodeID, new_parentID)

for List_of_Nodes in List_of_Nodes:
    print(Nodes(List_of_Nodes, List_of_Nodes))
```

This is what i put in:

```
The number of nodes: 2

Please enter a name: me
the number of parents for this node2
Please enter a parentName: father
Please enter another parentName:mother

Please enter another name: sister
the number of parents for this node2
Please enter a parentName: father
Please enter another parentName:mother
```

This is the output

```
nodeID: ('me', 'father') 
ParentID: ('me', 'father') 

nodeID: ('me', 'mother') 
ParentID: ('me', 'mother') 

nodeID: ('sister', 'father') 
ParentID: ('sister', 'father') 

nodeID: ('sister', 'mother') 
ParentID: ('sister', 'mother')
```

What i want it to output:

```
nodeID: me
ParentID: father, mother 

nodeID: sister
ParentID: father, mother
```

Comment: `List_of_Nodes = {}` why ?

Comment: Isnt it there all of my nodes are stored? @user5173426

Comment: `for List_of_Nodes in List_of_Nodes:
    print(Nodes(List_of_Nodes, List_of_Nodes))` This is obviously wrong!

Comment: well, i know, that is why I'm asking for help @user5173426

Comment: Try `for node in List_of_Nodes:`, then indented below that just `print(node)`.

Comment: I have tried that, it prints out the same thing, just without the "nodeID:" and "parentID" @martineau

Comment: @Luddeb123 were you able to solve this?

Comment: @user5173426 no, unfortunately not

Comment: @Luddeb123 okay, how about you edit your question with a breif description of what your code is suppose to do? Along with a sample I/O data.